Unity Gain Amplifier Purpose
In layman terms, what is the main use and purpose of unity gain amplifiers? I am reading that it is used to "buffer high impedance sources" but I'm unsure what this means practically.

Unity Gain applies only to the voltage. But current and hence power gain can still be very large, e.g. a million times.

My understanding as a total newbie is that without an amplifier, whatever components you place after your signal would draw power from the power source of the signal. This power source may be limited in some way, for example by series resistances. With an amplifier, those components would draw power from the power rails of the amplifier, which is able to provide more power than what the power source of the original source was able to. I believe the "zero output impedance" of an amplifier refers to exactly this concept, that there's no "series resistance" with the output of the amplifier.

Its just to separate output load and input so that they are isolated and there is no loading effect on output from input or the other way.

Unity gain generally refers to the voltage gain of an amplifier, but there is also current and power gain to consider.
The typical use for a unity gain buffer is to amplify the current while keeping the voltage the same. This is to transform from a high impedance that won’t load down the source to a low impedance that will be able to drive the load.
One example is in an audio amplifier, the output stage is often a push-pull emitter follower stage that has a voltage gain of approximately 1, but a high current gain. It buffers the earlier voltage amplifier stages in order to drive a low impedance speaker.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Another example is a voltage splitter to make a virtual ground for opamp circuits from a single supply such as in a battery powered device. A resistive voltage divider can be used to get Vcc/2 for the opamps, but there will be a trade off between the current available from it and battery life, lower value divider resistors will be able to handle more opamps but will be wasteful, higher value ones may not supply enough current. Current drawn from the divider will also change it's output voltage. So a divider using high value resistors is followed by an opamp in a unity gain buffer configuration to reduce drain on the battery while providing a low impedance Vcc/2 source whose voltage won't be affected by the load.

simulate this circuit

It means buffering the same signal out but with stronger current-providing ability, without loading the weak source signal by applying too much load.
For example if you have a weak source like a sensor or guitar output, it cannot provide much current to drive any load or even a long cable without being attenuated or degraded by noise or cable capacitance or getting loaded down too much.
Then you can put a buffer amplifier, with almost infinite input impedance that puts almost no load at all to the weak source.
The amplifier output can then drive a strong copy of the voltage waveform into some much heavier load like through longer cables to input of next amplifier.
Another example of a sensor with weak output that can't drive an analog input on a MCU, because MCU inputs may require a low impedance like 10kohms to drive the analog input. A sensor with 100kohm output impedance can't be accurately measured by MCU analog input. Then you can put a buffer with unity gain to drive sensor output to MCU input and problem is solved.

another example: an oscilloscope might employ a unity-gain buffer as its first stage, so that a probe attached sees a high input resistance in parallel with a small capacitance. That buffer may have to drive a much lower-resistance load at its output.

Short answer
The idea of a unity gain amplifier (voltage follower) is to copy the input voltage and apply the "copy" across the load. The clever trick here is that this copy is created by another voltage source (power supply), and not by the input voltage source. It is powerful enough to pass a high enough current through the load. Thus the voltage across the load is determined by the input voltage while the current through the load is determined by the very load. A funny analogy is an elephant copying the movement of an ant :-)
Basic idea
So, the first basic idea (aka "amplification") is to regulate the power (voltage) produced by an additional powerful voltage source and applied to the load. In addition, we do it by equalizing the "powerful copy" to the "weak original" (aka "negative feedback"). So the voltage follower is based on two great ideas - regulation and negative feedback.
I have revealed it below
through a series of CircuitLab experiments.
No negative feedback
Imagine that we are in the beginning of the 19th century at the dawn of electricity... and we wonder if it is possible to implement this idea in some way.
Perfect voltage source unloaded
To make the simplest possible electrical circuit, we need two elements - a voltage source and a load.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Perfect voltage source loaded
Let's then connect a 5 V perfect (with zero internal resistance) voltage source Vin to 1 kΩ resistor load RL. To monitor the current without cluttering the schematic, we can replace the load resistor with an ammeter with the same 1 kΩ internal resistance. As a result, a 5 mA current flows but the voltage does not change since the voltage source is perfect.

simulate this circuit
Imperfect voltage source loaded
Problem: If the voltage source has some internal resistance Rin (e.g., 1 kΩ), the load current "creates" an undesired 2.5 V voltage drop (loss) across Rin, and only the rest 2.5 V are applied to the load.

simulate this circuit
Unregulated load
We continue staying in the 19th century...
Remedy: We can say that there is a voltage drop VRin = Rin.IL because of two reasons:

There is an internal resistance Rin

There is a load current IL flowing through Rin


So, we can zero VRin either by zeroing Re or IL. The first is impossible because the input source is a given and we cannot change it. However, the second seems possible with a clever trick - if we do not take the current from the input source, but from an additional powerful voltage source. Let's do it by connecting a 10 V source Vcc to RL. Thus it transfers maximum power, voltage and current to the load.

simulate this circuit
Regulated load
We are at the middle of the 19th century...
But we want to regulate these electrical quantities, specifically the voltage. For this purpose, we connect a variable resistor Rce (representing the collector-emitter part part of the future 20th century BJT implementation), and obtain the well-known voltage divider.
When we vary Rce's resistance from zero to infinity, the divider "gain" (transfer ratio) varies from 1 to 0, and the output voltage VL across the load RL varies from 10 V to 0 V (the rest is across Rce). For example, to obtain 5 V, we have to set its resistance to 1 kΩ.

simulate this circuit
In fact, we have invented the amplification principle but we do not know it is called that because it is not written in any reputable books and it has not become a trite verbal cliché yet. By the way, this principle of regulation is insanely stupid because we throw away excess power, but it is what analog circuits are built on.
Negative feedback
We are moving towards the end of the 19th century... and we notice something unpleasant - if the load RL varies, VL will vary as well.
Conceptual circuit
We do not like these load voltage variations. So, we are clever enough and begin changing Rce to keep the load voltage constant.
For this purpose, we compare the load voltage with the input voltage by a null indicator NI (a sensitive voltmeter), and change Rce to zero the NI reading.

simulate this circuit
Actually, we operate according to the negative feedback principle but we are not aware of it because it is not officially announced in the textbooks ... it has not become another trite verbal cliché...
Emitter follower
We are already in the 20th century and we are fast moving forward in time...
We are eager to automate this manual arrangement, and we have many options - tubes (not presented in CircuitLab library), BJTs...

simulate this circuit
... FETs...
Source follower

simulate this circuit
Op-amp follower
... and op-amps.

simulate this circuit
To make the transistor circuits above close to perfect, I have added (with a small floating battery) a small bias voltage Vbias to the transistor inputs. There is no such need in the op-amp follower; it is perfect.
Summary
Finally, let's summarize all this wisdom in a few sentences. I will do it in collaboration with Gemini AI as I proposed two days ago in my EE meta question and answer.
Since Gemini is very intelligent and can handle almost everything, I just copied my answer as it is with the pictures (which Gemini still does not understand) and pasted it into its prompt window. Maybe, later I will clean it up and show to Gemini in a more decent way.
Gemini's writing is in italics; as you can see, it has done its job very well.
Gemini: The answer explains the concept of a unity gain amplifier (voltage follower) and how it works.
Key points:

A unity gain amplifier copies the input voltage but uses a separate power supply to provide enough current to the load.
It achieves this by regulating the power from the supply and using negative feedback to ensure the output voltage matches the input voltage.
The answer provides a historical perspective, imagining the development of the concept from the 19th century to the use of transistors and operational amplifiers.

See also a related answer of mine.

On the one hand this answer says Since Gemini is very intelligent and can handle everything, but it then says pictures (which Gemini still does not understand). This appears to be a contradiction.

@Chester Gillon, When necessary, I describe them to it verbally and it understands them very well.This is not a big problem;  it will learn to do that too. The problem is not with Gemini, but with us, humans.

When I have it do a summary, I just copy the whole text, clean it of some unnecessary service text, and give it to Gemini as a prompt. It grasps the general ideas amazingly well even without circuit diagrams.

I'll try to explain the purpose of a voltage buffer using a real-life example:
ONLINE STREAMING
You are performing something on the stage, but a very limited number of people are watching you. You want to be seen or heard by thousands or even millions.
Now, if you use a camera and stream your live performance over a media platform (social media or TV or something else) more people can watch live.

In the above example, the signal source is yourself, or your performance to be more specific, and the load is the audience.
The load is normally limited by the building you are performing in. This could be a performance centre, a theatre or somewhere else. The limit is basically the number of chairs or tickets. Now the online streaming tools (e.g. camera) work as buffer here:

the output is still the same i.e. your performance
the load capability is increased by a lot i.e. more people are now watching you

This is what mainly a unity-gain amplifier does.

When the signal source's output impedance (source impedance) is higher than the load impedance such that most of the signal will drop across the source impedance (i.e. the load will see only a small portion of the actual signal) then we can say "the source is not capable of driving this load".

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
A unity-gain amplifier (a.k.a. buffer) naturally has a very high (theoretically infinite) input impedance so if you use a buffer as a load then still most of the signal will drop across the load (buffer's input).
The buffer normally uses a separate power source to shape the output signal. That's a downside but driving heavier loads is not a free lunch. The output is equal to the input (frequency and amplitude). But a buffer has a very low output impedance (theoretically zero) so it can drive heavier loads.
That's the main purpose.

Looking for another explanation
I already answered the OP's question in one possible way. To solidify the idea of this legendary circuit, I will try to find another possible explanation of the idea behind it. I will do it in a quite unusual but, I hope, more interesting way - in the form of a dialogue between me and Gemini AI (I have proposed this answering technique in my meta question & answer). But let's ask what Gemini thinks about it (its answer is in italics):
CF: Gemini, does it make sense for a circuit to be explained in several different ways?
Gemini: Absolutely! Explaining a circuit in several different ways can be very beneficial for understanding. Here's why:

Different learning styles: People learn in different ways. Some learn best with visual aids like diagrams, others prefer a step-by-step breakdown, and some grasp concepts best through real-world analogies. Having multiple explanations allows people to connect with the material in a way that works for them.

Building a deeper understanding:  By seeing the circuit explained from different angles, you can gain a more comprehensive picture of how it functions. One explanation might focus on the overall function, while another dives deeper into specific component behaviors. This layering of information allows for a richer understanding.

Tailoring the explanation:  Depending on the audience, the level of detail and approach may need to be adjusted. For beginners, a high-level overview with simple analogies might be best. For more advanced learners, a mathematical analysis or in-depth component breakdown could be valuable.


So, the next time you encounter a circuit explanation, don't be afraid to seek out additional resources that present the information from a different perspective. It can significantly enhance your understanding!
CF: Okay, Gemini... I will do as you say. Remember you summarized my answer? I am running your summary as a prompt for your reference.
Gemini: The summary highlights a great explanation of a unity gain amplifier (voltage follower). It emphasizes the key points of how it replicates the input voltage while utilizing a separate power supply and negative feedback for precise output control. Additionally, it mentions a historical perspective, which is a great way to add context to the concept. I will review this summary and use it to inform my future responses to you.
What was the problem?
CF: Gemini, do you remember what happens to the output voltage Vin of an imperfect voltage source with source voltage V and 1 k internal resistance Rin when we load it with 1 k load RL? The load is represented by an imperfect ammeter. This ammeter has an internal resistance of 1 kΩ (RL) and functions as both the load and the measuring device.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Gemini: Yes, Circuit fantasist, I remember! When you connect an imperfect voltage source with source voltage V, 1 kΩ internal resistance (Rin), and a 1 kΩ load (RL), the output voltage (Vin, which refers to the voltage across the load in this case) will be lower than the source voltage (V). Here's why:
Internal resistance effect: The imperfect voltage source isn't ideal. It has an internal resistance (Rin) of 1 kΩ that acts like a voltage divider in series with the load (RL). This resistance "drops" some of the voltage from the source before it reaches the load.
Voltage divider effect: Because the internal resistance (Rin) and the load resistance (RL) have the same value (1 kΩ each), they will split the source voltage (V) equally.
Resulting output voltage: Therefore, the output voltage (Vin) across the ammeter (load) will be approximately half of the source voltage (V).
Here's an analogy: Imagine the voltage source as a water pump, the internal resistance as a narrow pipe section, and the load as another pipe section connected downstream. The pump represents the source voltage (V). The narrow section restricts water flow, similar to how the internal resistance reduces voltage. The downstream pipe section represents the load. Since both pipe sections have the same width, the water pressure reaching the end (the load) will be about half of what the pump can produce (the source voltage).
Formal calculation: We can use the voltage divider formula to calculate the exact output voltage (Vin):
Vin = V * (RL / (Rin + RL))
Plugging in the values (V, Rin = RL = 1 kΩ), you'll find that Vin is approximately V / 2.
In conclusion, the imperfect voltage source's internal resistance and the ammeter's internal resistance acting as the load cause the output voltage (Vin) to be significantly lower than the source voltage (V).
How to stop current
CF: Gemini, your explanation is great! Now that we have a good understanding of the problem, we need to find even more original explanations for its solution. What do you think, can we look at the problem from the following perspective?
The problem is that a current flows through the input source, and it creates a drop across its internal resistance. So, we need to somehow make this current stop flowing. Figuratively speaking, how do we “stop” current?
Stopping the current by extremely high resistance
The straightforward solution is to enormously increase the resistance. We cannot change the voltage V and internal resistance Rin of the input source; we can only increase the load resistance. The load is represented by an imperfect voltmeter. This voltmeter has an internal resistance of 1 GΩ (RL) and functions as both the load and the measuring device.

simulate this circuit
But we can connect additional devices in series or parallel. What then can we do to stop the current in another way?
Gemini's insight
Gemini: Sure, here is a more original explanation of how to "turn off" the current flowing through the input source, from the perspective of current:
Input current: When you connect the source to the load, a current flows through it. This current is caused by the voltage of the source and its internal resistance.
Goal: Our goal is to reduce or "turn off" this current to minimize the voltage drop and increase the voltage reaching the load.
Indirect "turn off": We can "turn off" the current indirectly by counteracting it.
Introducing an opposing current: We can introduce an opposing current in series with the input source. This opposing current will strive to counteract the input current, reducing or "turning off" it.
Stopping the current by equivalent opposing current
CF: Great, Gemini! Your idea of a "counteracting current" (to the input current) is really original. It can be created by a simple (not ideal) resistor-type current source Vop-Ropp. It is contrary connected in series to the input simple current source V-Rin. Thus the two equal but opposing currents destroy each other.

simulate this circuit
Stopping the current by equivalent opposing voltage
But can't we "stop" the current by a "counteracting voltage" (to the input voltage) instead? Then we can directly use this voltage as an output voltage applied to the load. It would be closer to the follower circuit where there are only voltage sources.

simulate this circuit
Gemini: That's a very interesting thought, Circuit fantasist! You're absolutely right that we can achieve a similar outcome by using a counteracting voltage instead of a counteracting current. In fact, this is precisely how a voltage follower circuit works! Here's a breakdown of your idea and how it relates to the voltage follower:
Concept: You propose using a counteracting voltage to directly oppose the voltage drop caused by the internal resistance of the source. This would effectively eliminate the voltage drop and provide the full input voltage to the load.
CF: Gemini, I think the additional voltage opposes the input voltage, and not the voltage drop across the internal resistance.
Gemini: You're absolutely right, Circuit fantasist! I apologize for the slight inaccuracy in my previous explanation. Here's a refined explanation that clarifies the concept of a counteracting voltage in a voltage follower circuit:
Counteracting the input voltage, not the voltage drop: In a voltage follower, the counteracting voltage doesn't directly oppose the voltage drop across the internal resistance of the source. Instead, it counteracts the entire input voltage.
Canceling out voltage drop (indirectly): By counteracting the entire input voltage, the op-amp indirectly eliminates the impact of the voltage drop across the source's internal resistance.
Overall effect: The net result is that the voltage appearing at the load (which is the output voltage) is very close to the original input voltage from the source. The voltage drop caused by the internal resistance is minimized, and the follower acts as a unity gain buffer.

simulate this circuit
In an op-amp follower, a properly supplied op-amp acts as the opposing voltage source Vopp.
Summary
Gemini, would you write a summary of our joint answer? I know you can do it better than me.
Gemini: Our conversation explored the concept of voltage reduction in an imperfect voltage source due to its internal resistance and investigated methods to minimize this effect.
Voltage Source with Load:

Problem: Connecting an imperfect voltage source (with internal resistance) to a load (represented by an ammeter with internal resistance) results in a lower output voltage at the load compared to the source voltage.

Cause: The internal resistance of the source acts like a voltage divider, reducing the voltage reaching the load.

Solution (Indirect): Increase the load resistance significantly (impractical in many cases).


Voltage Follower Circuit:

Concept: A voltage follower circuit uses an operational amplifier (op-amp) to create a counteracting voltage that cancels out the voltage drop caused by the source's internal resistance.

Mechanism: The op-amp's negative feedback loop ensures the output voltage is almost equal and opposite to the input voltage, effectively mimicking the input voltage at the output.


Benefits:

High input impedance: Minimizes current drawn from the source.

Unity gain: Output voltage is nearly identical to the input voltage.

Buffering: Isolates the load from the source while maintaining voltage level.


To OP
Gemini, what wish will you send the OP at the end? Would they benefit from our answer?
Gemini: Dear OP, I hope our response has been helpful and informative. We have endeavored to provide a clear and understandable explanation of the concepts of a voltage source with a load and a voltage follower circuit.
I believe our response can be beneficial to you in the following ways:

Deeper understanding: We have approached the problem from different perspectives, using both current and voltage analysis, which can help you build a deeper understanding of the subject matter.

Original insights: We have offered original perspectives on how to "turn off" current and how the voltage follower circuit works, which can stimulate you to look at problems in new ways.

Practical applications: We have described the advantages of the voltage follower circuit and its significance in electronic applications, which can be useful to you when designing or working with electronic systems.


We would like to encourage you to:

Explore additional resources to deepen your knowledge of the topic.
Ask us any questions you may have, related to this or other topics.
Share your thoughts and ideas on how we can improve our future responses.

